# Playback of audio attachments

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I have some basic timeline functionality working, as well as attachment uploads.  I have AAC audio in an mp4 container, if I upload it as video/mp4, tapping the card will playback the file with a blank video icon.  When uploading as audio/mp4, nothing happens when tapping the card.  I've also tried substituting an MP3 and using audio/mp3, with the same results.

Is audio attachment playback not working yet, or am I missing something here?

Ideally, I'd like to show the HTML template card, and have the audio playback triggered from an action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio attachments are not yet supported by the Glass client. The Glass team is discussing this feature. See [issue 73](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=73) on the official issue tracker, which was filed by the asker and was accepted by the Glass team.

Comment: Thanks for the response, filing now.

Comment: [Issue 73](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=73) filed.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a stopgap solution, you can attach audio as a video (video/mp4 in this case) and it will initiate playback.  Since the video player takes up the screen, you will not have any titles / html, just a blank video icon; I would suggest creating a bundle with some HTML for the cover, then insert the attachment in the bundle so that opening it initiates playback.